# XAML, ListBox, ListBoxItems

Tags: c, xaml

I am trying to get data on mouse click events. In `item.content` I see the necessary data, but it does not get them. I need to get the values of this object ... but I don’t know how. I would be very grateful for your advice or assistance.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    class Room_List
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string other { get; set; }
        public Room_List() { }
        public Room_List(string name, string ip, string status)
        {
            Name = name;
            IP = ip;
            Status = status;
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<Room_List> data_room_list = new ObservableCollection<Room_List>();
    /*ObservableCollection<Conference_Room> data_conference_room = new ObservableCollection<Conference_Room>();*/

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.DataContext = this;
        listbox_room_list.ItemsSource = data_room_list;

        //входные тестовые данные
        data_room_list.Add(new Room_List("Переговорная 101", "10.45.130.1", "fsdf"));
        data_room_list.Add(new Room_List("Переговорная 102", "10.45.130.2", "fs12df"));
        data_room_list.Add(new Room_List("Переговорная 103", "10.45.130.3", "fsf21df"));
        data_room_list.Add(new Room_List("Переговорная 104", "10.45.130.4", "fsderf"));
        data_room_list.Add(new Room_List("Переговорная 105", "10.45.130.5", "fsagsddf"));
    }
          private void PlaceholdersListBox_OnPreviewMouseDown2(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement(sender as ListBox, e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as ListBoxItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            // ListBox item clicked - do some cool things here
        }        }
    private void listBox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = listbox_room_list.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }    }    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it`s was easy...but not for me, I was prompted :)
    Room_List room_List = (Room_List)Item.Content;